# Is LDAP on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Are LDAP servers considered databases for the purposes of this site?

Comment: related : http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators/86#86

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd personally say so.  Just because it's not an RDBMS and doesn't speak SQL doesn't make it not a database.

When the [proposal was originally in area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4260?phase=definition), before it was renamed to 'database administrators', I put in a few questions referencing noSQL, heirarchical and network databases, and none of 'em got an off-topic vote.  (they didn't rise up to the top, but they weren't voted against)

Comment: How is administration of such data handled? Is it done by the DBA, or are they usually all managed by the application/device?

Comment: @Stan : what do you consider 'administration' ? There's still a person (although, not with the title 'DBA', but see the link above) who managed schemas, policies, replication, etc.